# How do I save a object to custom collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Sorry if I have mixed up the terminology, but I am trying to understand how I can save objects to custom collections dynamically. If I have a app that handles blogs I can only save my blogs to "/My-app/Blogs"

I want to be able to choose a sub-collection dynamically when saving like "/My-app/Good_blogs/Blogs" or "/My-app/Bad_blogs/Blogs"

This is my current code:

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json());

require('dotenv/config')

//Import Routes
const blogRoute = require('./routes/blogs')
app.use('/blogs', blogRoute)

//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOOSE_CONNECT, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },
    () => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))

app.listen(3000)
```

Blog.js (Schema)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const BlogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    message: String,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', BlogSchema)
```

blogs.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Blog= require('../models/Blog')

router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const blog = new Blog(req.body)

    await blog.save()
    res.sendStatus(200)
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: I am not sure, have you considered using a key in schema, something like `mongoose.Schema({
    message: String,
goodblog: Boolean
})`

Comment: Thanks, but to clarify I would want the possibility to add any number of blog-categories under "my-app". And my real usecase is not blogs, I only used it as en example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our comments I have deduced you are trying to add documents to a collection whose name is provided in a string. It is not recommended to have multiple collections with the same schema. What you should do is put all your blog posts in one big collection and add a property to query it by that will give you the posts you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "sub-collection", but you can make a property of type `array` and store more documents in it.

You can use a schema like so:

```
const BlogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    message: String,
});
BlogSchema.add({subBlogs: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: BlogSchema }]});
```

The `subBlogs` property just needs to be added after creation because `BlogSchema` is undefined until after creation.

`subBlogs` will now be an array of blog `_id`s, to which you can push new blogs into, and populate using Mongoose as you would populate any other data.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am pretty new to both node.js and mongoose. But in my current code, If I add an "blog_type" value to the "router.post" -function and extract the values separatly from the body. how would I modify my "blogs.js" to be able to save blogs under the new blog_type ?

Comment: @Burton It's not entirely clear what you're asking. A router is simply a way to catch HTTP requests to specific URL, you don't "add values" to them, so I'm not sure what you mean by that. Are you trying to create a recursive model where each blog contains more blogs?

Comment: The blogs is only an example. I receive post-requests containing blogs to blogs.js and want to be able to use some variable, maybe a value from the post-requests to be able to store the blogs under "db-name.value.blogs". Where "value" is a variable that is defined in the post-request

Comment: @Burton Ah! So you just want to insert the object into a new collection whose name is given by a string? This is possible, but not recommended. You should instead have one big blog collection, and have a property like `owner` or `type` or whatever to filter it by to get only the posts you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks that makes sense. Last question hopefully. Lets say that I change the blogs-usecase to companies and invoices. I create one database with "companies" and one database with "invoices", what would be a good way to link each invoice to the corresponding company?
Do I add the id that mongodb creates for each company to each invoice? Or is there any smarter way ?

Comment: @Burton Since we're getting off-topic, [let's continue this in a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202724/room-for-chrispytoes-and-burton)